# login and signup page creation using html css and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-development-server

I have created a login and signup page with the help of youtube videos but i have written all login and signup page code in index.html but i want to create separate login and signup page but when i try to do so both page are not linked together i didn't know javascript i just copied the code can anyone help me how to separate index.html login and signup page

I tried to separate index.html login and signup page but stuck in it please anyone can help

**login.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Responsive Login and Signup Form</title>

    <!--CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

    <!--Boxicons-->
    <link
      href="https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.4/css/boxicons.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
  </head>
  <body>

    <!--login page-->
    <section class="container forms">
      <div class="form login">
        <div class="form-content">
          <header>Login</header>

          <form action="#">
            <div class="field input-field">
              <input type="email" placeholder="Email" class="input">
            </div>

            <div class="field input-field">
              <input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="password">
              <i class="bx bx-hide eye-icon"></i>
            </div>

            <div class="form-link">
              <a href="#" class="forgot-pass">Forgot password?</a>
            </div>

            <div class="field button-field">
              <button>Login</button>
            </div>
          </form>

          <div class="form-link">
            <span>Don't have an account?
              <a href="signup.html" class="link signup-link">Signup</a></span>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="line"></div>

        <div class="media-options">
          <a href="#" class="field facebook">
            <i class="bx bxl-facebook facebook-icon"></i>
            <span>Login with Facebook</span>
          </a>
        </div>

        <div class="media-options">
          <a href="#" class="field google">
            <img src="icons8-google-48.png" alt="" class="google-img" />
            <span>Login with Google</span>
          </a>
        </div>

      </div>

    

  </body>
</html>
```

**signup.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Signup</title>

    <!--CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

    <!--Boxicons-->
    <link
      href="https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.4/css/boxicons.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />

</head>
<body>
    
    <section class="container forms">
        <div class="form signup">
            <div class="form-content">
                <header>Signup</header>
                <form action="#">
                    <div class="field input-field">
                        <input type="email" placeholder="Email" class="input">
                    </div>
    
                    <div class="field input-field">
                        <input type="password" placeholder="Create password" class="password">
                    </div>
    
                    <div class="field input-field">
                        <input type="password" placeholder="Confirm password" class="password">
                        <i class='bx bx-hide eye-icon'></i>
                    </div>
    
                    <div class="field button-field">
                        <button>Signup</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
    
                <div class="form-link">
                    <span>Already have an account? <a href="login.html" class="link signup-link">Signup</a></span>
                </div>
            </div>
    
            <div class="line"></div>
    
            <div class="media-options">
                <a href="#" class="field facebook">
                    <i class='bx bxl-facebook facebook-icon'></i>
                    <span>Login with Facebook</span>
                </a>
            </div>
    
            <div class="media-options">
                <a href="#" class="field google">
                    <img src="icons8-google-48.png" alt="" class="google-img" />
                    <span>Login with Google</span>
                </a>
            </div>
    
        </div>
        </section>

</body>
</html>
```

**style.css**

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;500;600&display=swap');


*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.container{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: #4070f4;
    column-gap: 30px;
}

.form{
    position: absolute;
    max-width: 430px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 30px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    background: #fff;
}

.form.signup{
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.forms.show-signup .form.signup{
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}

.forms.show-signup .form.login{
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
}

header{
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #232836;
    text-align: center;
}
form{
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.form .field{
    position: relative;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 20px;
    border-radius: 6px;
}

.field input,
.field button{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;
    border-radius: 6px;
}

.field input{
    outline: none;
    padding: 0 15px;
    border: 1px solid #CACACA;
}

.field input:focus{
    border-bottom-width: 2px;
}

.eye-icon{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 10px;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #8b8b8b;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 5px;
}

.field button{
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #0171d3;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.field button:hover{
    background-color: #016dcb;
}

.form-link{
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.form-link span,
.form-link a{
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #232836;
}

.form a{
    color: #0171d3;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.form-content a:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.line{
    position: relative;
    height: 1px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 36px 0;
    background-color: #d4d4d4;

}

.line::before{
    content: 'Or';
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #232836;
    padding: 0 15px;
}

.media-options a{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

a.facebook{
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #4267b2;
}
 
a.facebook .facebook-icon{
    height: 28px;
    width: 28px;
    color: #0171d3;
    font-size: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.facebook-icon,
img.google-img{
    position: absolute; 
    top: 50%;
    left: 15px;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

img.google-img{
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    object-fit: cover;
}

a.google{
    border: 1px solid #CACACA;
}

a.google span{
    font-weight: 500;
    opacity: 0.6;
    color: #232836;
}
```

**script.js**

```
const forms = document.querySelector(".forms"),
pwShowHide = document.querySelectorAll(".eye-icon"),
links = document.querySelectorAll(".link");

pwShowHide.forEach(eyeIcon => {
eyeIcon.addEventListener("click", () => {
  let pwFields = eyeIcon.parentElement.parentElement.querySelectorAll(".password");
  
  pwFields.forEach(password => {
      if(password.type === "password"){
          password.type = "text";
          eyeIcon.classList.replace("bx-hide", "bx-show");
          return;
      }
      password.type = "password";
      eyeIcon.classList.replace("bx-show", "bx-hide");
  })
  
})
})      

links.forEach(link => {
link.addEventListener("click", e => {
 e.preventDefault(); //preventing form submit
 forms.classList.toggle("show-signup");
})
})
```

Comment: create a signup.html and login.html and move the code there and access it by adding a link to the file <a href="/signup.html">Signup</a>

Comment: well i tried to do the same thing but when i click on login it goes on next page but showing only blue page

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of javascript to link 2 html pages. Simply HTML tags are enough.
Create 2 html files signup.html & login.html. Paste code for login in login.html and code of signup in signup.html
Add below code in login.html to link it to signup page

```
<a href="/signup.html" class="link signup-link">Signup</a></span>
```

Add below code in signup.html to link it to login page

```
<a href="/login.html" class="link signup-link">Signup</a></span>
```

Comment: bro i tried but when i click on signup button it goes on signup page but whole page is on blue colour